# Does TMUX have unit tests or a test suite?

Tags: tmux, testing

I am going through my configuration shell scripts and I have found the `make` commands to run test suites for pretty much every "big" open source project that I use (`vim`, `zsh`...) except for tmux. I can't find anything documented that says I can run `make test` or something of the sort to ensure everything is in order before I `sudo make install`.

Does anybody know?

Comment: I don't think there are that kind of tests for tmux. You best bet will be to ask on their mailing-list.

Comment: I don't have the tmux source, but have you tried `make check` (you mention "something of the sort", but just to be clear and explicit) -- this is a GNU-ish synonym for test and usually either one or the other (but not both) is used.

Comment: I did try it. `make check` is defined (perhaps the configure script puts it in) but it runs nothing. It is a valid target.

Comment: This is added for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

tmux does not use unit tests or something like a big automated test suite. Also there is no check target or something similar in the Makefile.

Anyhow there are some files which support a quick non automated test under /tools/, for example:

- /tools/UTF-8-demo.txt which contains a lot of UTF-8 ASCII Art examples
- /tools/256colors.pl which prints out a color palette
- /tools/putty-utf8.sh which lets you check if special characters work with putty

If there is something wrong with the output, you will have to recognize it by yourself, because it will be some optical difference. Errors in the output could also lead to for example a wrong terminal configuration and not necessarily a problem with tmux.